# call a php variable on hover using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mouseover

I have a variable `$form` in PHP and want it to be called or displayed whenever I hover a button.
I am a novice in ajax and don't know how to call the variable on hovering the button.
The code is:

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#login_button").hover(function() {
            $("login-form").slideDown(400);
        });
        $("#login_button").hover(function() {
            $("login-form").css('visibility','visible'); 
        });
        $("#login_button").dblclick(function() {
            $("login-form").slideUp(1200);
        });
        $("#login-form").mouseleave(function() {
            $("login-form").slideUp(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$form = "<form action='?' method='post' id='login-form' name='login-form'><!-- class='form-horizontal well' -->
         <strong><legend>Login</legend></strong>
         <fieldset id='inputs'> 
             <input type='text' placeholder='Username' name='name' class='input-large' id='username'>
             <input type='password' placeholder='Password' name='password' class='input-large' id='password'>
         </fieldset>    
         <fieldset id='actions'>    
             <input type='submit' id='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Sign in'>
             <div class='forgot'>  
                 <strong><a href='?forget=1' id='forget'>Forgot Password?</a></strong>
             </div>
         </fieldset>
         ";
?>
```

Comment: a closing tag `</form>` is missing, and there is some errors (you use `$("login-form")` instead of `$("#login-form")` for example) in your javascript but the principle seems good

Answer (score 3):

You can using jquery post to get value and send it to your url :

```
  $("#yourID").hover(function(){
      $("fomr").css({visible:visible});
      var url = "your-url-here";
      var username = $("#input-for-username").val();
      var password = $("#input-password").val();

      //init ajax post
      $.post(url,{username:username,password:password}.function(data){
        //any thing here
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

No AJAX required;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var php_var = '<?php echo json_encode($form); ?>';          
});
```

Use it like:

```
$('#element').hover(function() {
  $('#form_container').html(php_var);
}, function() {
  $('#form_container').html('');
});
```

Comment: I suppose this will result a syntax error because form contains simple quotes (and newlines )

Answer (score 1):

php is server-side and javascript (like html) is client-side.

What you have to do is display the content of `$form` in your page inside a hidden container, then use a trigger to display it:

```
<div id="login-form" style="display:none"><?php echo $form; ?></div>
```

For the js part, I simplify your example:

```
$("#login_button").hover(function(e) {
  $("#login-form").slideDown(400);
},
function(e) {
  $("#login-form").slideUp(1200);
});
```

[jquery.hover doc](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Notice the current version of jquery use this syntax:

```
$(document).on("hover", "#login_button", function(e){
  // your commands here
});
```

Comment: This is the best solution to this SPECIFIC issue. the $form element does not change, so put it on the form in a hidden element. Clean and efficient. I only use ajax for elements which are dynamic or change server side.